# Telegram bot (webhook) + ngrok

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, webhooks, ngrok

I have a project telegram bot on ASPNet Core 3.1, C# (webhook), which works in conjunction with ngrok
When I run the project from visual studio, everything works fine, the bot accepts commands and returns responses, in the ngrok console the response = 200 OK
But when I run .exe from the directory where the project was built, it doesn't matter debug or release, then the bot does not work, and the response 502 bad gateway is returned in the ngrok console
What could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Did you instruct ngrok to [overwrite the host header](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-host-header)?

Comment: yes i'm rewriting the header like this:
ngrok http -host-header = localhost 61950
in launchSettings.json i have
 "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61950",